# How to create a virtual file with inode that has references to storage in memory

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, kernel

Let me explain clearly.

The following is my requirement:

- Let's say there is a command which has an option specified as '-f' that takes a filename as argument.
- Now I have 5 files and I want to create a new file merging those 5 files and give the new filename as argument for the above command.
- But there is a difference between

  1. reading a single file and
  2. merging all files & reading the merged file.
- There is more IO (read from 5 files + write to the merged file + any IO our command does with the given file) generated in the second case than IO (any IO our command does with the given file) generated in the first case.

***Can we reduce this unwanted IO?***

In the end, I really don't want the merged file at all. I only create this merged file just to let the command read the merged files content.

And to say, I also don't want this implementation. The file sizes are not so big and it is okay to have that extra negligible IO. But, I am just curious to know if this can be done.

So in order to implement this, I have following understanding/questions:

- Generally what all the commands (that takes the filename argument) does is it reads the file.
- In our case, the filename(filepath) is not ready, it's just an virtual/imaginary filename that exists (as the mergation of all files).
- ***So, can we create such virtual filename?***
- ***What is a filename?*** It's an indirect inode entry for a storage location.
- In our case, the individual files have different inode entries and all inode entries have different storage locations. And our virtual/imaginary file has in fact no inode and even if we could create an imaginary inode, that can only point to a storage in memory (as there is no reference to the storage location of another file from a storage location of one file in disk)
- But, let's say using advanced programming, we are able to create an imaginary filepath with imaginary inode, that points to a storage in memory.
- Now, when we give that imaginary filename as argument and when the command tries to open that imaginary file, it finds that it's inode entry is referring to a storage in memory. But the actual content is there in disk and not in the memory. So, the data is not loaded into memory yet, unless we read it explicitly. Hence, again we would need to read the data first.

***Simply saying, as there is no continuity or references at storage in disk to the next file data, the merged data needs to be loaded to memory first.***

So, with my deduction, it seems we would at least need to put the data in memory. However, as the command itself would need the file to be read (if not the whole file, at least a part of it until the commands's operation is done - let it be parsing or whatever). So, using this method, we could save some significant IO, if it's really a big file.

So, how can we create that virtual file?

- My first answer is to write the merged file to tmpfs and refer to that file. But is it the only option or can we actually point to a storage location in memory, other than tmpfs? tmpfs is not option because, my script can be run from any server and we need to have a solution that work from all servers. If I mention to create merged file at /dev/shm in my script, it may fail in the server where it doesn't have /dev/shm. So I should be able to load to memory directly. But I think normal user will not have access to memory and so, it seems can not be done without shm.

Please let me know your comments and also kindly correct me if my understanding anywhere is wrong. Even if it is complicated for my level, kindly post your answer. At least, I might understand it after few months.

Comment: With some juggling you could make the process read from a named pipe (and let the *producer* write to that pipe) `What is a filename?` It is a directory entry containing a *pointer to*  an inode. (its number)

Comment: Hi, actually I can only supply the filename argument and I can not hack it as it's a binary file

Comment: Since: (1) you can't change the command [binary blob]. (2) don't care about the output file (3) can't stop the command from writing to the output (4) only want the command to read the input files. Try: `cmd -f /dev/null f1 f2 f3 f4 f5`. That is about as fast as it gets. Any reason why that wouldn't work?

Comment: @CraigEstey I do not understand why you have mentioned /dev/null. However, I tried it didn't work. The command takes only one file as argument. For now, I have created a condition to check for /dev/shm and create the combined file there if it exists, else to create in /tmp/. I am curious if someone can answer this with programming approach.

Comment: My named pipe solution is very real (and it actually works!). But I am afraid you didn't understand it. (BTW *binary file* : you mean the executable, or the actual data file whose name is supposed to be supplied as an argument to the executable?)

Comment: My bad, I hadn't had my coffee, yet :-) I assumed that `-f` specified an _output_ file. The named pipe approach wildplasser mentioned is the correct one. To consolidate: `mkfifo wtf ; cat f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 > wtf & ; cmd -f wtf ; rm wtf`. This works just as well as if you could specify: `cat f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 | cmd -f -` if `cmd` understood that `-` meant `stdin`

Comment: what do you mean with **combine** files? are you appending, xor-ing, adding byte by byte... substracting... ???? you have been let to explain clearly, but you haven't done at all.

Comment: Hi, I meant appending. I haven't tried the mkfifo yet. I have heard about the concept. But may be it should work in this case. I will try it now.

Comment: If you mean appending, why didn't you say it at first?  have you tried the `cat(1)` command anyway.  It's there from ancient times of unix, and nobody has developed an alternate way to concatenate files since then.  You sould use `cat f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 > combined_file.txt` and that's all!

Comment: @LuisColorado Hmm..It seems you have not read my entire question :)

Comment: @JeevanPatnaik, not, I haven't, You begun telling you where to explain clearly something and neither explain at all what you mean with combining files nor clear explanation of what you expect, and no code at all, so explain it better and i'll be able to answer it, instead of debating in the comments.

Comment: Whatever type of combining files, it should be done. However, I have my answer

Comment: I need to check a few things before that and will update

Answer (score 0):

Create a fifo (named pipe) and provide its name as an argument to your program. The process that combines the five input files *writes* to this fifo

- `mkfifo wtf`
- `cat file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 > wtf` # this will block...
- [from another terminal] `cp wtf omg`

---

Here I used `cp` as your program, and `cat` as the program combining the five files. You will see that `omg` will contain the output of your program (here: `cp`) and that the first terminal will *unblock* after the program is done.

---

Your program (here:`cp`) is not even aware that its 1st argument `wtf` refers to a fifo; it just opens it and reads from it like it would do with an ordinary file. (this will fail if the program attempts to seek in the file; seek() is not implemented for pipes and fifos)

Comment: why do you think combining means concatenating files? why not merging them somehow? or adding byte by byte mod 256? how many ways of combining files there are in the universe?

Comment: @LuisColorado it is just a *minimal* example. And since combining the five files is done in a separate process, it could be *any* process. Besides: the OP was not very clear about how to combine the five files.

Comment: @wildplasser, *was not very clear* ??? I would add *was not clear at all*